# Can I used appConfig tied to parameter store to access aws secrets

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, aws-parameter-store, aws-app-config

I know that appConfig can work with parameter store.  I also know that parameter store can work with secrets manager.  But can you reference aws secrets in appConfig through parameter store?